# html input range style using background-image

Tags: html, css, input

I ma trying to style input range and progress. The issue is they are not aligned on top of each other. I dont want to use margin-top on -webkit-slider-runnable-track because I found it doesnt work in some cases (depending on where parent element is positioned).

```css
 :root {
   --value: 30%;
 }

.seekbar-wrap{
  background: #353b49;
}

.seekbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 1;
}
.seekbar-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 50px;

}
.load-level {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.load-level::-webkit-progress-bar{
    background:none;
}
.load-level::-webkit-progress-value{
    background-color:#b6bfc1;
}
.load-level::-moz-progress-bar{
    background-color:#b6bfc1;
}
.input-progress {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #62768f;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.input-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,currentColor var(--value,0),transparent var(--value,0));
    border: 0;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.input-progress::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.input-progress::-moz-range-track {
    height: 5px;
    border: 0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,currentColor var(--value,0),transparent var(--value,0));
}
.input-progress::-moz-range-progress {

}
.input-progress::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none; 
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="seekbar-wrap">

  <progress class="load-level" min="0" max="100" role="progressbar" value="44.11733725" aria-hidden="true">% buffered</progress>

  <input class="input-progress" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" autocomplete="off" role="slider" aria-label="Seek" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="235" aria-valuenow="17.052851513822205" value="0" aria-valuetext="00:01 of 00:20" style="user-select: none; touch-action: manipulation;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understood what you mean, but maybe this CSS code could help:

```css
:root {
   --value: 30%;
 }

.seekbar-wrap{
  background: #353b49;
}

.seekbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 1;
}
.seekbar-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
  display:flex;

}
.load-level {
/*     position: absolute; */
    top: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.load-level::-webkit-progress-bar{
    background:none;
}
.load-level::-webkit-progress-value{
    background-color:#b6bfc1;
}
.load-level::-moz-progress-bar{
    background-color:#b6bfc1;
}
.input-progress {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #62768f;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.input-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,currentColor var(--value,0),transparent var(--value,0));
    border: 0;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.input-progress::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.input-progress::-moz-range-track {
    height: 5px;
    border: 0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,currentColor var(--value,0),transparent var(--value,0));
}
.input-progress::-moz-range-progress {

}
.input-progress::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none; 
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it but it doesnt work, they are both at the top. They need to be centered inside the seekbar-wrap.